# Creating a cell array of different randomized matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, variable-assignment, vectorization

I'm trying to create a cell array of size N,
where every cell is a randomized Matrix of size M,
I've tried using deal or simple assignments, but the end result is always N identical Matrices of size M
for example:

```
N=20;
M=10;
CellArray=cell(1,N);
CellArray(1:20)={rand(M)};
```

this yields identical matrices in each cell, iv'e tried writing the assignment like so:

```
CellArray{1:20}={rand(M)};
```

but this yields the following error:

**The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.**

the ends results should be a set of transition probability matrices to be used for a model i'm constructing,
there's a currently working version of the model, but it uses loops to create the matrices, and works rather slowly,
i'd be thankful for any help

Comment: what's wrong with the loop solution? Surely, this is not the performance-critical section of the code...

Comment: I'm not sure, this isn't the actual code, and the actual code needs to generate 500 of these, and then create some additional variables bases on these matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use loops because you are interested in a low execution time, get rid of the cells.

```
RandomArray=rand(M,M,N)
```

You can access each slice, which is your intended MxM matrix, using `RandomArray(:,:,index)`

Comment: This sounds like a great solution! ill give it a try

Comment: @ronimb And if you really need a cell array: add `RandomArray = mat2cell(RandomArray,M,M,ones(1,N));` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`cellfun`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
N = 20;
M = 10;

CellArray = cellfun(@(x) rand(M), cell(1,N), 'uni',0)
```

For every cell it newly calls `rand(M)` - unlike before, you were assigning the same `rand(M)` to every cell, which was just computed once.